# Best practive for linking an entity to multiple other ones with symfony2 / doctrine 2

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using symfony2 and doctrine 2 and I have a media entity that I used to store files linked to many other entities in a oneToMany relationships. So i have recipes, products, users, jobseekers, recipeSteps, etc, all having a link to the media entity.

Now, I have 13 of those other entities linked to media and it gets a bit messy.
Example :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\FoodAnalytics\Recipe", inversedBy="medias")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="recipeId", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $recipe;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\FoodAnalytics\RecipeStep", inversedBy="medias")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="recipeStepId", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $recipeStep;
```

Is there not a simpler way for managing this, that would still allow me to use ORM mapping : recipe->getMedias() and media->getRecipe() ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way is to specify each relationship as a standalone relationship in your Media entity.

You basically have a property called $medias which is currently holding 13 relationships. Split these 13 into the actual relationships, like Recipe and RecipeStep, so you have 13 properties instead of 1.
Then create a public method in your Media entity which is called getMedias, which returns all the related Entities.

The other option is to use a Mapped Superclass and extend your Entities from it, but that would require quite some refactoring to implement. 
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses

Comment: that's what I am currently doing. I was hoping there would be something implying less code redundancy